# Regex for word space comma seperated numbers

Tags: java, regex

I've following strings that I want to match via regex

```
XYZ 8,4
XYZ 13,5
```

Basically, a predefined word (XYZ)to be strictly matched followed by space and comma seperated numbers with each number of max length 2

I've another set of strings that needs to be regex matched

```
XYZ A 8.2.3
XYZ A 12.3.2
```

Here, a predefined word (XYZ A) with spaces to be strictly matched followed by space and dot seperated numbers with each number of max length 2 in the format (digit.digit.digit)

Appreciate any pointers

Comment: What have you tried so far? Because it looks like you asking for us to give you everything, not just pointers.

Comment: You posted what you want to achieve but didn't describe problem which is stopping you from achieving it. Have you tried anything? What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one that should work for both: http://regexr.com/3f27q

This is how it looks in java:

```
Pattern.compile("^((XYZ)|(XYZ A))\\W(\\d+[,.])*\\d+$");
```